# Do you know which field does hold account picture?

Tags: account

I am wondering if there is any field which holds account picture field ?

Comment: did you check the [account Object Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_account.htm) ?

Answer (score 1):

It is `PhotoURL`

> Path to be combined with the URL of a Salesforce instance (for
>   example, https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/) to generate a URL to
>   request the social network profile image associated with the account.
>   Generated URL returns an HTTP redirect (code 302) to the social
>   network profile image for the account.
>
> Blank if Social Accounts and Contacts isn't enabled for the
>   organization or if Social Accounts and Contacts is disabled for the
>   requesting user.

References

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_account.htm
- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=social_networks_overview.htm&type=5